# Load and Edit Specific Data Previously Filled

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a notes app and my notes are autosaved to Firebase Database. So far a user can make their own notes but cannot edit them. I want the app to open the same note (meaning the title and desc fields will hold the data entered last time) if clicked so they can edit it but don't know how, I don't even know what to look for online as this is my first project.

### New note creation & autoupdate

(One listener for title and one for body)

```
public class NewNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    private EditText editText, etd;
    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()/* THIS!*/.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("posts").push();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.etx);
        etd = findViewById(R.id.etdx);



        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", databaseReference.getKey());

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                map.put("title", editText.getText().toString());
                databaseReference.setValue(map);


            }
        });

        etd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                map.put("desc", etd.getText().toString());

                databaseReference.setValue(map);

            }

        });
        }
```

### Display the notes

(and set onClick action)

```
 adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, final Model model) {

                holder.setTxtTitle(model.getmTitle());
                holder.setTxtDesc(model.getmDesc());
                //holder.setmId(model.getmId());

                holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Here I need to find somehow to get back to the note I clicked on

                    }
                });
            }

        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### This is how the list looks

Since I'm not able to post images yet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY3zI.png

Each block is a note. (Ignore the B)

Comment: What's wrong with the code that you have shared?

Comment: @AlexMamo It's not wrong I just don't know how to make it do what I need. It allows me to save but I cannot edit what I saved after leaving the page.